# Navigate in inner tab

Tags: flutter

I want navigate in inner tab.
I have tree tabs, in the first tab I want that I can click in a button and go to another Screen, but without launch a new fullscreen over the screen with tabs.

In my code, I want that when I'm in the HomeScreen I can go to another screen like a subapp. How can I go?

that is my TabController code:

```
return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
          ],
        ),

        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            HomeScreen(), //-> Go to the SelectedItemScreen
            Screen2(),
            Screen3(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: This may be useful: https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf

Comment: Thanks, if you want to make a answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

This may help: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18546#issuecomment-397885240

You should hold a reference to this `TabController` and do `tabController.index = 0`.

Comment: I want that in the HomeScreen I launch a new screen.